# Can you help me to prove that this integral $\int_{1}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}}\,dx$ converges/diverges?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

To prove that this integral converges/diverges.

$$\int_{1}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}}\,dx$$

I have tried to solve this apllying comparison theorem, and to find the upper bound I did ridiculous simplifications and I got that the original function is smaller than $$\frac{1}{x}$$ which is divergent. Hence the original one also diverges. I don’t think that I have applied the theorem appropriately and I need help with another way to get the answer

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you. Otherwise your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to explain any thoughts I have

Comment: @SofiaIbragimova, you are absolutely right, the integral diverges.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Actually, I am still insecure with my solution

Comment: You should be insecure. Smaller than divergent establishes nothing. You need bigger than divergent — or a limit comparison result as for series.

Comment: Thank you, does it mean that I have to find the function smaller than the original one and prove that it diverges? Hence the original also diverges

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Note, for example, that $\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}\le 2x^3$ for $x\ge 1$.

Answer (score 3):

For large $x$
$$
\frac{x^2+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}}\sim\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^6}}=\frac{1}{x};
$$
thus by comparing to the convergence of the integral $\int_1^\infty\mathrm dx/x$ you can conclude that
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}}\,\mathrm dx
$$
diverges.

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Fine.

Answer (score 2):

We have simple estimates explicitly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{1}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}}\;dx
&\ge
\int_{1}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{\sqrt{x^6+4x^3+4}}\;dx
=
\int_{1}^\infty\frac{x^2+3}{x^3+2}\;dx
\\
&\ge
\int_{1}^\infty\frac1{x+1}\;dx
=\infty
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x \geqslant 1$,
$$x^6+x^3+2=\left(x^3+1\right)^2+\left(1-x^3\right) \leqslant\left(x^3+1\right)^2$$

$$\frac{x^3+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^3+2}} \geqslant \frac{x^3+3}{\sqrt{\left(x^3+1\right)^2}}=\frac{x^2+3}{x^3+1}>1$$

$$
\because \int_1^{\infty} 1 d x=\infty, \quad \therefore \int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^3+3}{\sqrt{x^6+x^4+2}} \text { is divergent. } 
$$